# Spying on object properties in Angular testing

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

Suppose I have an object with keys that call a method from the same service with different parameters. For example:

```
const myObject = {
    keyOne = myService.get('valueOne'),
    keyTwo = myService.get('valueTwo')
};
```

Is there a way, using `Jasmine`, to spy on each of the methods inside of this object?

```
const keyOneSpy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(myObject, 'keyOne');
const keyTwoSpy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(myObject, 'keyTwo');

// Perform some action

expect(keyOneSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('valueOne');
expect(keyTwoSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('valueTwo');
```

Comment: You want to `spyOn(myService, 'get')`. You can't spy the properties of `myObject` because they are values, not methods.

Comment: Why don't you just do `expect(myObject.keyOne)` ?